# Draw a tree with $4$ vertices of grade $5$, $8$ of grade $4$, $6$ of grade $3$, $10$ of grade $2$ and $36$ of grade $1$

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Draw a tree with $4$ vertices of grade $5$, $8$ of grade $4$, $6$ of grade $3$, $10$ of grade $2$ and the rest of grade $1$.

---

First of all "the rest" is obviously $36$. In theory there should be $64-1=63$ edges.

Does someone know a page to sketch this tree or can someone draw it? I am not able to find at least one of them of all the possible trees.

Comment: Line up the four grade $5$ vertices linearly and connect; attach two grade $4$ vertices to each grade $5$ vertex and then extend the 'arms'.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof thank you for the comment! How can I interpret "Line up the four grade $5$ vertices linearly and connect"? I mean we put $4$ vertices next to each other, but how can we connect them with others to have them to be of grade $5$? I do not understand.

Comment: You connect the outer one to the grade-5 vertex next to it, and two grade-4 vertices. You still need two other connections; complete those by adding grade 1 vertices.